# Write a script to get the line number of a file with "while read LINE", but failed

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/sh
num=1
cat $1 | while read LINE
do
        num=`expr $num + 1`
done
echo $num
```

Comment: "cat $1 | wc -l" get 6. but according the above scripts, I always get the initial value "1.Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your script is spawning a sub-shell when you use pipe after *useless* `cat`. All the changes to `$num` made inside sub-shell get lost after while loop ends and you get back to parent shell.
2. You should initialize `num` with `0` not `1`
3. It is better to not to use all capital letter variable names to avoid collision with internal shell variables.
4. Instead of reverse tick you should use `$(...)` for command substitution.

You should use:

```
#!/bin/sh
num=0
while read -r line
do
   num=$(expr $num + 1)
done < "$1"
echo $num
```

Comment: So it is. Thanks so much

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped.